# Algorithm to detect solid image

Tags: qt, image-processing, qimage

What is the best way to detect and mark it with rectangle on the images? Like picture below :

[image]

I am working with QtImage.
What i am thinking now is just find the first non transparent pixel then create 1x1 rect, then make it bigger and bigger until don't get the transparent pixel. Not sure if it really optimize. Please let me know if some of you have another method to do it.

Comment: What's the format of your image (argb?), I will make my answer more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV to do the job for you. It has a method [cvFindContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) which will give you back the set of contours, each one being a vector of points. From each set you compute the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates an you have your rectangle.

You will need to preprocess your image to a 8bit mono-channel image where all "transparent" pixels are set to 0 and all others are set to something else. Unfortunately, Qt has no grayscale built-in so you will need to prepare a buffer by hand.

Comment: I will check it. First need to integrate the the OpenCV with QT. Will post here when it success. :)